# React native - Programmatically check if in usb debugging is enabled/disable

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I want to implement proper mechanisms to detect "USB Debugging" status during the application runtime. The application should not run on such devices if it is in the enabled state.

So, Are there any native or built-in functions in react native?